# "OAuth2 not granted or revoked" when trying to evaluate free trial in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to offer a free trial period for my Chrome extension and have been following the Chrome [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment) about how this can be accomplished.

When my extension loads, though, the background script is logging the following error to the console:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: OAuth2 not granted or revoked.

The console is pointing at the call to `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` as the culprit. Here's the relevant code in my background script:

```
var CWS_LICENSE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/';

chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    'interactive': false
}, function(token) {
    console.log('token', token);

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', CWS_LICENSE_API_URL + chrome.runtime.id);
    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            var license = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            console.log('license', license);
        }
    };
    req.send();
});
```

My manifest is setup like so (some pieces omitted for brevity):

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"key": "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk",

"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "identity",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/"
],
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "cccccccccc.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
}
```

Here's what I've tried or confirmed:

1. The client id matches the value in the Google developer console that was generated using my extension's id.
2. The Chrome Web Store API is enabled in the Google developer console (it is the only API enabled).
3. The key in the manifest matches the value generated after I put the extension on the web store.
4. Calling `getAuthToken` with interactive mode enabled results in the same error.
5. I compared my code to [this example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/one-time-payment) and nothing jumps out at me as being substantially different (although an extra pair of eyes to confirm wouldn't hurt).

In case it matters, I'm using Chrome 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) on Mac OS X.

Any ideas about what is causing the error and what I need to change to make it go away so I can lookup the auth token and license?

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you're doing and I was wondering, what should I put as the referrer url in the Google Apis console. The Api key for the chrome web store Api

Comment: @Kerndog73 - I don't recall having to enter a referrer in the Google APIs console. I enabled the Chrome Web Store API and created a Client ID. The URL for that Client ID corresponds to the `client_id` in my `manifest.json` file. You may want to ask a new question on SO and provide more detail and a screenshot. Link to it here and I'll check it out.

Comment: Nah I won't worry about it. It's optional but highly recommended. That's still optional enough for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Code-wise, the only change needed is to enable interactive mode:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    'interactive': true
}, function(token) {
    ...
});
```

There were also a couple of PEBCAK issues going on. Namely:

1. It can take a few seconds for the interactive auth page to appear. This seems to be a bandwidth issue. This may be part of why the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken) suggests triggering the auth request on some kind of user interaction and not when the extension first loads.
2. Flipping interactive between `false` and `true` and reloading the extension was not a sufficient test of functionality. The result of `getAuthToken` is cached. When I revoke the auth and then refresh or even delete and re-add my extension the same token continues to be returned for some amount of time. Restarting Chrome with interactive mode enabled is what got me to this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how can I remove permissions that I gave *initially* to the extension? Now even if reinstall the extension, it doesn't ask me permission (in my case to manage Drive files) and returns the access token. I want the extensions to ask me a permission again after I reinstalled it. I also tried to remove chached token `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(
              { 'token': token }, function () {})` but it seems unrelated to permissions and didn't help.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Great question, but it's probably better asked as a new question on SO instead of in a comment. If you post a new question, by all means link to it here though!

Comment: I have been trying to use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` for the last 6 hrs and it was not even getting fired. Just changed `interactive: true` to `'interactive': true` and now its working. Can't understands why it was causing such issue!

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case the problem was related to the **Brave browser**:

If you are using this browser too, you probably will need to enabled the option `Allow Google Login for extensions` in this section [brave://settings/extensions](https://brave://settings/extensions).

**Explanation:**

> When this option is enabled: It **enables chrome.identity** for extensions
> so extensions can retrieve an OAuth token from google to authenticate
> users. ([Read more](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/wiki/Allow-Google-login---Third-Parties-and-Extensions))